# Is it code legal to mark neutrals that actually are neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring

USA/NEC question,  Another recent question has a white wire which is marked with tape, but is actually a neutral.  So what?

Suppose you have 4 neutrals running in a raceway, and you need to distinguish them because they go to different things: one goes to a MWBC lighting circuit, another to outlets which need a GFCI breaker, etc.

So you put different color tape on each neutral.

Is that allowed?

Citations in NEC would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's a code section that covers this. You shouldn't use colored tape/markers, as that reidentifys it as an ungrounded (hot) conductor (200.7(C)(1)). Using numbered wire marker labels is one common solution.

Comment: Sorry guys, please excuse my brain fart about the neutral

Answer (score 5):

#### Identifying Multiple Neutrals To Its Own Branch Circuit

The best way to do this is to use wire numbering stick-on labels, which solves the whole "what color can I use" question.  Each current carrying conductor of a single branch circuit is tagged with the SAME number. For example, all the  current carrying conductors of the branch circuit "kitchen lights" are tagged with the number "5".

[image: wire markings like these]

#### To make even better, the numbering system corresponds to the breaker location.

Here is a pic of a panel I did recently.
[image]

Comment: +1 *just* for leaving yourself enough wire length to reach any breaker in the panel. Good answer too.

Answer (score 3):

A white conductor is just that, a white conductor. Just because it is white does not automatically make it a neutral. So in your switch loop example, it is NOT a "neutral" that is re-marked, it is a white conductor.

A neutral, or more properly a "grounded conductor" smaller than #4 must be white or grey along it's length. It cannot be re-marked just at the ends.

You cannot label neutrals with other colors. If you need to identify another way use numbers or labels.

**2011 NEC**

> **Article 200 Use and Identification of Grounded Conductors**
>
> **200.6 Means of Identifying Grounded Conductors**
>
> **(A) Sizes 6 AWG or Smaller.**
>
> An insulated grounded conductor of 6 AWG or smaller shall be
>   identified by one of the following means:
>
> (1)    A continuous white outer finish.
>
> (2)    A continuous gray outer finish.
>
> (3)    Three continuous white stripes along the conductor’s entire
>   length on other than green insulation.
>
> (4)    Wires that have their outer covering finished to show a white
>   or gray color but have colored tracer threads in the braid identifying
>   the source of manufacture shall be considered as meeting the
>   provisions of this section.
>
> **(B) Sizes 4 AWG or Larger.**
>
> An insulated grounded conductor 4 AWG or larger shall be identified by
>   one of the following means:
>
> (1)    A continuous white outer finish.
>
> (2)    A continuous gray outer finish
>
> (3)    Three continuous white stripes along its entire length on other
>   than green insulation.
>
> (4)    At the time of installation, by a distinctive white or gray
>   marking at its terminations. This marking shall encircle the conductor
>   or insulation.

For switch loops:

> **200.7 Use of Insulation of a White or Gray Color or with Three Continuous White Stripes**
>
> **(C) Circuits of 50 Volts or More.**
>
> The use of insulation that is white or gray or that has three
>   continuous white stripes for other than a grounded conductor for
>   circuits of 50 volts or more shall be permitted only as in (1) and
>   (2).
>
> (1)    If part of a cable assembly that has the insulation permanently
>   reidentified to indicate its use as an ungrounded conductor by marking
>   tape, painting, or other effective means at its termination and at
>   each location where the conductor is visible and accessible.
>   Identification shall encircle the insulation and shall be a color
>   other than white, gray, or green. If used for single-pole, 3-way or
>   4-way switch loops, the reidentified conductor with white or gray
>   insulation or three continuous white stripes shall be used only for
>   the supply to the switch, but not as a return conductor from the
>   switch to the outlet.

Comment: I'm not asking about how to mark switch loops, I mentioned them in parentheses as a counterexample of what I'm not talking about.  I'm asking if it's legal to re-mark white wires which actually are neutral.  I edited to be clearer.  200.7 says relabeled hots must be labeled, but it doesn't say whether neutrals can't be.

Comment: @Harper, then 200.6(A) & (B) are your answers. To be honest I don't get your question. If they are white, and are used as a neutral, why would you need or want to re-mark them???

Comment: Then the question is too ambiguous. If the wire is white, and being used as a neutral, what color are you re-marking it to???

Comment: Well, in a case like this you certainly could mark a white wire as grey. Since it is already white it meets code as a grounded conductor, marking it grey is above and beyond. Keep in mind, for multi-wire circuits in conduit you must also bundle them as to their respective grounded circuit conductors. 210.4(D)

Comment: If I need to track specific neutrals I use white tape and write on it or a label maker. In my area no other color is allowed (white / grey) except for a multi wire cable as listed. Speedy gave all the references, a continuous white or grey. Adding a colored tape not allowed here for a neutral. + speedy

Comment: 200.7c is inapplicable, it clearly states that it only applies to wires which are not grounded conductors.   If 200.6 really means "continuous", then it also would outlaw what you do, number tape or any other method.

Comment: @Harper, which is why I wrote that 200.7(C)(1) was for switch loops only. I put it there for comparison.

Comment: I've cleaned up the off-topic comments; please keep them on-topic and constructive, and consider moving to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) if discussion continues. See http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment for more information.

Comment: FWIW, @harper, I think this does address your question in that it tells you that you can't mark the neutrals with colored tape, but doesn't address the side question of **how** to mark the wires to indicate their different purposes. Can you offer any advice there, @SpeedyPetey?

Comment: To me, "continuous outer finish" means how the wire is manufactured. If "finish" includes tape markings, it falls apart: a white wire marked with gray tape would be barred under 200.6a (meets none of the numbered conditions).  Ditto a wire marked with wire marker or tag.  How do you bundle wires if the tape you bundle them with counts as a "finish"?  And a brown wire wrapped with white tape would be *legal* if the markings were continuous.

Comment: A white wire with grey tape would be perfectly fine under 200.6(A) since both colors apply in that section. They grey would only be for identification, but the conductor is still white along it's length. .... Also, bundling tape would NOT be considered a finish IMO. Same goes for tags or wire markers. That's kind of absurd.

Answer (score 2):

New in the 2014 NEC:

> **200.4(B) Multiple Circuits.** Where more than one neutral conductor associated with different circuits is in an enclosure, grounded circuit conductors of each circuit shall be identified or grouped to correspond with the ungrounded circuit conductor(s) by wire markers, cable ties, or similar means in at least one location within the enclosure.
>
> Exception No.1: The requirement for grouping or identifying shall not apply if the branch-circuit orfeeder conductors enter from a cable or a raceway unique to the circuit that makes the grouping obvious.
>
> Exception No.2: The requirement for grouping or identifying shall not apply where branch-circuit conductors pass though a box or conduit body without a loop as described in 314.16(B)(1) or without a splice or termination.

Your method of identifying different neutrals with phasing tape could possibly be considered under "or similar means" if it is just a single wrap of tape. This method could be confused as re-identification as an ungrounded conductor though, even by experienced electricians and especially by novices.

Less confusing methods such as, white conductors with colored tracers, tie wraps, labels, or wire numbers should be employed.